# GlutKeyboardFunc callback doesn't work in openGL

Tags: glut

I am trying to simply quit the application on pressing a key in openGL and the keyboard doesn't seem to work.
Neither am I am not able to quit the application just by clicking on the close button of the window. Any explanation for this behaviour? **I am not recreating the window continuously either.**

Here's the code snippet

```
void keyboardfunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
cout << "Inside" ;
switch (key) {

case 'q': exit(0);
default: break;

}


int main(int argc,char ** argv) 
{ 



.
.
.
glutReshapeFunc(reshape_func);


glutDisplayFunc(draw);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardfunc);
myinit();

glutMainLoop();


return 0; 
}
```

The program is to simulate insertion sort by representing the array graphically , using a for loop I am clearing the screen every time and representing the numbers as histogram each time

**Just to be clear the simulation of insertion sort works , only the keyboard callback doesn't work.**

Comment: @Jose Maria Sorry here is the complete [code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c_Odpp0rFZAWbTt7FdxGDFSS1KhTHG9Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your draw functions take the CPU control and don't let to execute GLUT events loop. Take into account that GLUT is single thread.

You must register a timer. Timer will produce new rendering. Each second compute next iteration and force to redraw scene.

```
void draw(){
  renderHistogram();
}

void timer(int value) {
  getNextIteration();
  glutPostRedisplay();
  glutTimerFunc(1000, timer, 1); // executed on a second
}
```

To register timer include this line before glutMainLoop:

```
glutTimerFunc(1000, timer, 1); // executed on a second
```

next iteration function would be:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
void getNextIteration()
{
    if (i == n) {
        // Array is sorted
        return;
    }

    int key;
    key = arr[i];

    if (j == 0 || arr[j] <= key) {
        // Internal loop finished, reset j, and advance i;
        arr[j + 1] = key;
        i++;
        j = i - 1;
    }

    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
    j = j - 1;
}
```

Comment: But how does this affect the working of keyboard callback?

Comment: @Rabbid76 There is a loop with sleep, until all the sorting process is finished, no returns to glutMainLoop, so events aren't processed.

Comment: I proposed the solution. Not include sleep in the display func. Display only has to render and exit. A timer will produce new rendering after an elapsed time.

Comment: @Kitwradr Your display function is executed for a long time, and events aren't processed.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Draw is rendering all the sorting process. Display must render a step, and exit without sleep. If he calls glutPostRedisplay then will create a very fast animation.

Comment: any idea how to implement the getNextIteration() function? since I am calling the display events in for loop

Comment: Added getNextIteration to the solution.